# -bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Input/output error

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, gcc

I am using debian on bananaPi. Yesterday, I ran an object file (which I already had build a few days ago), and it was working fine. Now I made some changes to the source and when I tried to build the file it is giving this error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Input/output error
```

This is the command which I used to build the file:

```
gcc sensor.c -o result -lwiringPi -lsqlite3 -lrt
```

Comment: Is *sensor.c* in current directory? Why don't you write a makefile?

Comment: "Now i made some changes to the source"  what changes?  Try running this command and check for any disk error. "tail -f /var/log/messages"

Comment: Try to `cat` all files which are used while compilation including the destination o file if exists to see which one produces the error message (I assume you should get the same error). Perhaps you have corrupted filesystem.

Comment: Try `ls /usr/bin/gcc` it seems like you can't access it. Maybe hardware error.

Comment: I'd say it is either bad sectors, or your media was disconnected (and everything else was still in cache or on another media)

Comment: this is for `c` code not `c++` code so please remove the `c++` tag.

Comment: could it be the media that is holding the source is full?

Comment: Probably your hard disk is broken. Check `/var/log/messages`